# Random forest visualization in python

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, random-forest

```css
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e7781de34abc> in <module>
      3                feature_names = fn,
      4                class_names=cn,
----> 5                filled = False);
      6 fig.savefig('rf_individualtree.png')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in plot_tree(decision_tree, max_depth, feature_names, class_names, label, filled, impurity, node_ids, proportion, rotate, rounded, precision, ax, fontsize)
    174         proportion=proportion, rotate=rotate, rounded=rounded,
    175         precision=precision, fontsize=fontsize)
--> 176     return exporter.export(decision_tree, ax=ax)
    177 
    178 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in export(self, decision_tree, ax)
    565         ax.set_axis_off()
    566         my_tree = self._make_tree(0, decision_tree.tree_,
--> 567                                   decision_tree.criterion)
    568         draw_tree = buchheim(my_tree)
    569 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in _make_tree(self, node_id, et, criterion, depth)
    546         # traverses _tree.Tree recursively, builds intermediate
    547         # "_reingold_tilford.Tree" object
--> 548         name = self.node_to_str(et, node_id, criterion=criterion)
    549         if (et.children_left[node_id] != _tree.TREE_LEAF
    550                 and (self.max_depth is None or depth <= self.max_depth)):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in node_to_str(self, tree, node_id, criterion)
    340                                           np.argmax(value),
    341                                           characters[2])
--> 342             node_string += class_name
    343 
    344         # Clean up any trailing newlines

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str
```

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL
import pydot
import warnings
from sklearn import tree
from glob import glob
from IPython.display import display, Image
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
%matplotlib inline
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

df = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')

df.head()

x = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'target']
y = df.loc[:, 'target'].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2,random_state=0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)


rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                            random_state=0)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)

fn=features = list(df.columns[1:])
cn=df.target


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=800)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[0],
               feature_names = fn, 
               class_names=cn,
               filled = False);
fig.savefig('rf_individualtree.png')
```

---

i am  following this structure for visualizing my random forest graph

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkH71.png

so when i write the highlghited code i get the error 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not “numpy.int64”) to str

im using the dataset from kaggle " https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci "

would appreciate if you can help me

Comment: It's probably because at some point (tree.plot_tree) the code is asking for strings but you're giving it integers. Do me a favor an include in your code right before plot_tree type(fn), type(cn), type(fn[0]), type(cn[0]) and see if any of them isn't a string or a list. If that's is the case, instead of type you should write fn=[str(x) for x in fn], fc=[str(x) for x in fc].

Comment: Also, if you wrote the code instead of posting a picture, people can test the code faster than copying what the image says. Same goes with the error, if you wrote all what it said, it makes it easier to get right to the line that is giving you the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response , i have upload the whole code

Comment: i have just upload it at html console , sorry im new here , so not much familiar with features and also seems can not use a lot of features as im new too , hope you can help me

Comment: sorry if I sounded too harsh, the solution is on the way.

Comment: no worries , i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `class_name` in `plot_tree` requires a list of strings but in your code cn is a list of integers (numpy.int64 to be precise). All you need to do is convert that list to strings and problem solved.

```
#some code before
fn=features = list(df.columns[1:])
cn=df.target

#conversion from list of numpy.int64 to list of string
cn=[str(x) for x in cn]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=800)
tree.plot_tree(...
#some code after
```